# Accessing the URL query string in HTML, without Javascript

Tags: html, url, svg

I want my page to show a parameter in the query string, without using Javascript.

For example, this is my `test.html` file:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    The parameter is:
  </p>
  <p>
    * I want this text to be replaced with the value of param1 in the query string
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user accesses it using this URL: `test.html?param1=value1`, then I want it to show this in the browser:

> The parameter is:
>
> value1

Effectively, I want the html that the browser runs as being:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    The parameter is:
  </p>
  <p>
    value1
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible, without using Javascript?

The reason for my question is that I want to make a web page with SVG, which would animate according to the URL query string used to access the page. This is my first step, to try to access the URL query string within the HTML.
And I can't use Javascript in the page, because of my target audience!

I know it can be done easily using Javascript, but my target audience have the javascript disabled, so this doesn't work.

I thought it might be possible using CSS, but I can't figure out how to make CSS parameters take the values from the URL query string.

Comment: You'd need something to generate the page i.e. a web server that has some hosting language such as PHP or javascript. You can then generate whatever page you want without it needing javascript to run in the browser.

Comment: It is simply not possible to access the query string with plain html. CSS is only for styling, so it's not possible either.

Comment: @Geilmaker Thank you! But regarding your comment about CSS: all I really want to do is to style it - but based on the URL query string. Is it possible to make a CSS variable take the value of one of the parameters in the URL query string?

Comment: Yes it is, but not without javascript or any webserver.